# Using Try/Catch block to set file path?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out an assignment for my Visual Basic course. I am told to assume that a given text file is not in the \bin\Debug folder of my program, so I am trying to throw an exception error and get the correct path from the user via an inputbox but nothing appears to happen, or the variable isn't being set, I'm not entirely sure which. I have my code below, any hints as to why this will not work for me?

Thanks!

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim sr As IO.StreamReader
    Dim age As Integer
    Dim path As String
    Try
        sr = IO.File.OpenText("Ages.txt")
        age = CInt(sr.ReadLine)
        txtOutput.Text = "Age is " & age
    Catch exc As IO.FileNotFoundException
        path = InputBox("File Ages.txt not found." & vbCrLf & "Please enter the correct path to the file.", _
                 "Example: C:\Documents\My Text Files")
    Catch exc As InvalidCastException
        MessageBox.Show("File 'Ages.txt' contains an invalid age.", "Warning!")

        Try
            sr = IO.File.OpenText(path)
        Finally
            txtOutput.Text = "Age is " & age
        End Try
    Finally
        Try
            sr.Close()
        Catch

        End Try
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: when you say nothing appears to happen, do you mean the InputBox isn't being display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner Try/Catch block should be inside the FileNotFoundException catch.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim sr As IO.StreamReader
    Dim age As Integer
    Dim path As String

    Try
        sr = IO.File.OpenText("Ages.txt")
        age = CInt(sr.ReadLine)
        txtOutput.Text = "Age is " & age
    Catch exc As IO.FileNotFoundException
        path = InputBox("File Ages.txt not found." & vbCrLf & "Please enter the correct path to the file.", _
                 "Example: C:\Documents\My Text Files")
        Try
            sr = IO.File.OpenText(path)
        Finally
            txtOutput.Text = "Age is " & age
        End Try
    Catch exc As InvalidCastException
        MessageBox.Show("File 'Ages.txt' contains an invalid age.", "Warning!")
    Finally
        Try
            sr.Close()
        Catch

        End Try
    End Try
End Sub
```

An even better solution would be...

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim age As Integer
    Dim path As String = "Ages.txt"
    Dim fileFound As Boolean = False

    While Not IO.File.Exists(path)
        path = InputBox("File Ages.txt not found." & vbCrLf & "Please enter the correct path to the file.", _
                     "Example: C:\Documents\My Text Files")
    End While

    Using sr As IO.StreamReader = IO.File.OpenText(path)
        If Integer.TryParse(sr.ReadLine, age) Then
            txtOutput.Text = "Age is " & age
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("File 'Ages.txt' contains an invalid age.", "Warning!")
        End If
    End Using

End Sub
```

This will first check if the file exists, and continue looping until the user enter ones that does. This allows you to remove the FileNotFoundException catch.

This also uses Integer.TryParse to check if the value was casted correctly, allowing you to remove the InvalidCastException catch.

Lastly, opening the reader with a Using statement eliminates the need for a finally/nested try-catch block, as Using implements this internally.

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that the exception being thrown is not an `IO.FileNotFoundException`, so your `InputBox` code is never being hit.  [`OpenText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.opentext(v=vs.110).aspx) can throw quite a few types of exception.  There are several ways you can go about doing this without an exception ([File.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) comes to mind), but to continue on this route I would change your exception handling to something like this:

```
Catch exc as Exception
    If TypeOf exc Is InvalidCastException Then
        '...
    Else
        path = InputBox(....)
    End If
End Try
```